# Only return slimmed down version of feed

Tags: yahoo-pipes

I'm trying to create a new yahoo pipe that will only returned a slimmed down version of an xml.

Say my original XML looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<name>Joe bloggs</name>
<age>31</age>
<description>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse aliquam metus id eros blandit vel convallis nunc accumsan. Fusce adipiscing eros a enim feugiat vestibulum. Cras vulputate malesuada neque vel ultricies. Nunc commodo condimentum risus, eu interdum odio rutrum ut. Nullam nec neque eget dolor tristique dignissim sit amet non nibh. Donec sagittis, elit eget tempus laoreet, tellus eros gravida nunc, eu elementum sem turpis eget velit. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Donec sed nibh nec arcu feugiat malesuada nec sollicitudin neque. Morbi egestas gravida blandit. Praesent luctus ipsum sed sem porta a tempus ipsum congue. Cras non lectus metus. Fusce non purus quam, vel convallis urna. Aenean dignissim consequat tincidunt. Nunc posuere pulvinar est, id pretium sem vestibulum non</description>.
```

I'm trying to create a yahoo pipe that will change the tag names, in which I'm using the rename module, and it works fine.

Now, I'm wanting to get rid of the description tag, so my XML only returns name and age.

How can I do that with yahoo pipes?

Cheers in advance for any help

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use the "Create RSS" module as the last step in the chain.  Then only include the fields you want.

Comment: That won't allow me to return fields with custom names will it?

Comment: Oh, ok... you can used Item Builder inside a Loop.  Name your own fields and then assign values to each from the existing XML feed.  You can then either "emit" those as a slimmed down feed, or nest those within a new field in the original feed.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Regex module on the description field and replace `.*` with an empty textfield. That deletes the field.

Comment: That's exactly what I needed. And it does it quickly. Thanks